# Sites never load due to fonts.googleapis.com

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet, microsoft-edge

An issue with loading websites has suddenly developed on my Windows 10 PC. Many sites never load on Chrome because they are *Waiting for fonts.googleapis.com* forever: one example is [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/). GitHub Pages sites don't work either. On Edge, these sites sometimes load with no CSS, and other times don't load at all.

I have also been noticing some other network issues lately, such as YouTube videos occasionally not loading in Chrome while working fine as an embed in Discord.

No other devices on my router have any of these issues.

How should I diagnose and resolve this?

Comment: Do you have any extensions in chrome? You could try to [reset](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en) your browser or even uninstall and reinstall it. To determine what's going on you could open the developer tools in Chrome by pressing F12. Then click on the network tab and reload the page. It should tell you what elements it couldn't load. There may also be useful error messages on the console tab.

Comment: @SpiderPig Resetting my browser didn't help, and incognito (where I believe extensions are disabled) doesn't make a difference. In devtools, the font from Google Fonts remains "Pending" forever.

Comment: Does chrome work correctly on other machines in the same network?

Comment: Perhaps a DNS problem or caching problem with your ISP. Try using [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). Also try disabling your firewall. [More info](https://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-waiting-fonts-googleapis-com/).

Comment: @SpiderPig Other machines work fine.

Comment: @harrymc I've tried Google DNS (it's what I use on my devices anyway) and BT's DNS. I will give disabling my firewall a go.

Comment: You could try [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html). Find the exact url that won't load and then load it with `curl -v https://url`. Next you could use tools like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). You could also try and connect through a proxy server or a vpn to see if the problems disappear.

Comment: @harrymc I tried flushing my DNS and it didn't make a difference, nor did disabling Windows Firewall.

Comment: Try to boot in Safe mode with Network.

Comment: @SpiderPig Fiddler reports that fonts.googleapis.com returns a totally empty response.

Comment: @harrymc I'll try that.

Comment: @harrymc It works in Safe Mode! How can I narrow down the problem further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem and struggled with it for a few days. I eventually figured out that turning off BitDefender (my anti-virus program) made the problem go away.

Comment: So your workaround solution was to disabled your antivirus security protection?

Comment: I do actually use BitDefender - I'll try switching to something else when I have access to that computer again.

Comment: @Facebook, yes that's correct. Disabling my antivirus security protection solved the problem for me. After re-enabling the antivirus protection, the problem actually didn't come back as of yesterday, but I will have to keep an eye on it. If it comes back, perhaps I'll need to try other antivirus software.

Comment: This worked! As you said, it even stills works after BitDefender was turned back on. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're welcome. The problem eventually came back for me. I sent an issue report to BitDefender. If they provide any useful response, I will update.

By the way, my initial thought was to call Dell to ask them for help. I don't have a software warranty for the machine, so they wanted $89 for their assistance. No thanks.

Comment: I just heard back from an engineer at BitDefender. The engineer asked me to get the latest updates for BitDefender. He said to make sure I am on build 1.0.9.52 and see if the problem goes away. I haven't tried that yet, but I will try to remember to do so. I had actually already uninstalled BitDefender, since it was continuing to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have no problems when booting in Safe mode with Network, your problem
is caused by some installed product or plugin.

To identify the problem :

- Try another browser. If the problem disappears then some plugin of Chrome is to blame.
- Use
  [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
  to disable selectively startup programs, then re-enable,
  until you find the product responsible for the problem.